# How to combine inline style and external import const style in JSX React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So for example I want to do something like this:

```js
const style = {
  color: 'red'
}

<div style={style + { width: '10%' }}>Hello</div>
```

To combine the style in the constant and inline in JSX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to combine objects.

```js
const style = {
    color: 'red'
};

<div
    style={{
        // Spread out previous `style` properties
        ...style,
        width: "10%",
    }}
>
    Hello
</div>
```